# Which instruction doesn't involve, as a source for operation, register "a" in a multicycle datapath

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, state-machine, cpu-registers, microprocessors

[image: Here the datapath multicycle]

I know that the **j** instruction doesn't involve the use of the register "a" as a source for his operation, what I'm not sure is if for the **sw** and **lw** instruction is the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question with the details needed to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: An SW instruction has 2 register sources, one for data and one as part of the addressing mode.  So pretty obviously it needs both outputs from the register file, unless you want it to read the register file in 2 different cycles.  LW only has one register source; the other is destination only.

Comment: `lw` and `sw` are I-Type instructions.  Both require the ALU to perform an addition for the addressing mode, to compute the memory address: the ALU adds Read data 1, "A", to the sign extended 16-bit immediate, which then becomes the write address.  Also have a look at the `jal` and `lui` instructions.